# I have question about the operator space theory

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-spaces

[image: I have question about the operator space theory. How to solve equation (2.2.1) in details]

I have question about the operator space theory. How to solve equation (2.2.1) in details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for any $a\in M_n(V)$,
$$
\varphi_{n+1}\left( \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \right) = \varphi_n(a)
$$
And
$$
\left\|\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\right\|_{M_{n+1}(V)} = \|a\|_{M_n(V)}
$$
Does this help?

Comment: MANY THANKS THE ISOMERTY PROPERTIES IS USEFUL TO PROVIDE EQUATION 2.2.1